# PCL (point cloud library) 1.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS build error

Tags: point-cloud-library, ubuntu-16.04

I updated Ubuntu version from 14.04 lts to 16.04 lts 
and got problems when building projects that utilizes point cloud library.
(It used to work well on Ubuntu 14.04 and I build my projects with qtcreator)

The warning messages I have are :

> warning: libboost_system.so.1.54.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libpcl_common.so, may conflict with libboost_system.so.1.58.0
>
> warning: libboost_thread.so.1.54.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libpcl_common.so, may conflict with libboost_thread.so.1.58.0
>
> warning: libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libpcl_io.so, may conflict with libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
>
> warning: libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libpcl_io.so, may conflict with libboost_iostreams.so.1.58.0
>
> warning: libboost_chrono.so.1.54.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libpcl_io.so, may conflict with libboost_chrono.so.1.58.0

and the errors are :

> ~/main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::PCLVisualizer(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, bool)'
>
> ~/main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::setPointCloudRenderingProperties(int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, int)'
>
> ~/main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::setPointCloudRenderingProperties(int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, int)'
>
> ~/build-Desktop-Default/CMakeFiles/project_name.dir/main.cpp.o:-1: In function `pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor::OrganizedNeighbor(bool, float, unsigned int)':
>
> ~/main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `pcl::search::Search::Search(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, bool)'
>
> ~/build-Desktop-Default/CMakeFiles/project_name.dir/main.cpp.o:-1: In function `pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor::OrganizedNeighbor(bool, float, unsigned int)':
>
> ~/build-Desktop-Default/CMakeFiles/project_name.dir/main.cpp.o:-1: In function `pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor::OrganizedNeighbor(bool, float, unsigned int)':

I can see there's conflict between `libboost_system.so.1.54.0` and `libboost_system.so.1.58.0` but how can I solve it?

Comment: 16.04 comes with a different version of Boost. You need to reconfigure and rebuild PCL (or any library that uses Boost that you have built from source for that matter).

Comment: I got the same error and I presume it was because the upgrade to 16.04 also upgrade the version of libboost and PCL need to reconfigure and build. Building the PCL1.8 right now and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

For building pcl from source on 16.04, please follow this 
[tutorial](https://larrylisky.com/2014/03/03/installing-pcl-on-ubuntu/).
But there is then no reason to not build PCL 1.8 instead of 1.7.x, as it is downward compatible.

In addition the Jochen Sprieckerhof repository for 1.7.2 is outdated for 1.7.2, as in Ubuntu 16.04 there is a native [repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/pcl). You can simply do

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libpcl-dev
```

I recommend a clean un- and reinstall in one of the proposed ways.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should download this file [PCL-1.8-linux.deb](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rysdi2mga1ch388/PCL-1.8.0-Linux.deb?dl=0),

And run this code:

```
sudo dpkg -i PCL-1.8-linux.deb.
```