# Error in install point cloud library ubuntu16.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, point-cloud-library

I want to install pcl on ubuntu16.04. in terminal I typed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/cpl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpcl-all
```

but

> Reading package lists... Done
>       Building dependency tree
>       Reading state information... Done
>       E: Unable to locate package libpcl-all

How can solve it?

Comment: it means that package libpcl-all does not existe on repos

Answer (score 4):

The ppa location you listed appears incorrect. It should be:

```
ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
```

However, `apt-cache search libpcl-all` returns nothing on my system also running 16.04.

You could use `apt-cache search libpcl` and maybe choose a different package to install?

The answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711172/pcl-point-cloud-library-1-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-build-error) post installs `libpcl-dev` (PCL 1.8) from the Ubuntu [repo](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/pcl) using:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libpcl-dev
```

This [guide](https://larrylisky.com/2016/11/03/point-cloud-library-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) provides an alternative installation method for 16.04.